# Debian Installer Making RAID with some RAID Devices

Tags: debian, raid, mdadm, installation

I'm setting up a brand new file server using Debian Squeeze. I have a mixed setup of disks where I have 500GB x 4 and 1TB x 3 all SATA and a small 2GB Transcend IDE Flash module for the base OS install.

I would like to setup two RAID-0s from the 500GB drives and then use those two raid devices and the 1TB drives to make a large RAID-5 array.

Maybe this will make it clearer:

```
RAID-0 md0 = sda1 & sdb1 (Formatted to Linux Auto-raid)
RAID-0 md1 = sdc1 & sdd1 (Formatted to Linux Auto-raid)
RAID-5 md2 = md0, md1, sde1, sdf1, sdg1 (Formatted to Physical LVM)
LVM: /var (1GB) /tmp (1GB) swap (2g) /data (rest of space)
```

(I realize this setup is a little bizarre and you probably have many issues with the way its setup but this is the *best* option I have given the current situation of the disks and where the data on those disks is located)

Booting up the Debian Installer gets to the partitioner, I can make the initial two RAID-0 devices, however when I try to format those devices to "Physical Volume for RAID" that is NOT an option. Once out of the installer and booted into a debian install, I can make the RAID devices no problems at all.

What gives? Am I missing something? Should I try to Alt over to a BusyBox terminal and format the RAID devices that way, then see if the Debian installer lets me setup the drives the way i want? Should I give it another go now that the RAID devices are created? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok I figured it out. Basically have to setup the raid devices and formatt them prior to running the debian installer, then install and can setup the LVM and everything is kosher. Must be a Debian bug.

Comment: I've never created a compound array using the Debian installer so I'm not sure if this is expected. As you are installing "testing" it might be a new issue in that release that is worth reporting if you can find the relevant place to file a query or bug report.